# Embedding of $H^s$ into $L^p$ for $p$ sufficiently big

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am reading a book about Euler equation and at some point we aim to prove the existence of global solution in 2D and I struggle with a point in the proof. We have a strong solution of the Euler equation $u \in L^\infty([0,T], H^s)$ with $\nabla \cdot u = 0$ for $s > d/2 + 1 = 2$ (here $d$ is the dimension). We can see that $\omega \in H^{s-1}$ as
$$|\hat \omega(t, \xi)| \le C|\xi||\hat u(t, \xi)|.$$
Now the author claims that the $L^p$ norm of $\omega $ for every $p$ sufficiently big vanishes, i.e.
$$\frac{d}{dt} \| \omega(t) \|_{L^p} = 0.$$
However I don't really get why we can even consider this $L^p$ norm, a priori $\omega$ is not even in this space. Is there any embedding of $H^s$ into $L^p$ for $p$ sufficiently big that I am missing?

Comment: Well, when $s > d/2+1$, $H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is embedded into $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (continuous functions tending to $0$ at infinity) because $(s-1) > d/2$. This is (for example), stated as case (3) of Proposition 4.18 in Demengel & Demengel's book "Functional Spaces
for the Theory
of Elliptic Partial
Differential
Equations".

Comment: Going to zero at infinity may not be sufficient for being $L^p$, $1/x$ goes to $0$ at infinity.

Comment: But $\omega \in H^{s-1}$ and $s-1 > 0$ so $\omega \in L^2$ (just using the basic remark that the $H^{\sigma}$ norm bounds the $H^0 = L^2$ one). So $\omega \in L^p$ for every $p \geq 2$ (by Hölder's inequality, because both in $L^2$ and $L^\infty$).